# Python caldav Attribute Error

Tags: python, caldav

I just installed caldav 0.5.0 using pip on Windows. I tried to use this code from the documentation:

```
from datetime import datetime
import caldav
from caldav.elements import dav, cdav

# Caldav url
url = "https://user:pass@hostname/caldav.php/"

client = caldav.DAVClient(url)
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'caldav' has no attribute 'DAVClient'
```

Does someone know what causes this issue?

Comment: You most likely have a file called caldav.

Comment: No, my python file is called calendar.py...

Comment: There is no file in your current directory called caldav?

Comment: No, not that i know...

Comment: Caldav 0.5.0 is very old, please upgrade.  0.8.0 was released some few days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your file is named `calendar.py`, which causes some kind of collision somewhere. Renaming your file to something else will do the trick (it did for me).

Comment: Correct answer, several others have had this issue.